# 'OR' condition in the CASE STATEMENT in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, case

I wanted to know if it is possible to have a condition like:

```
((CASE WHEN (a = 1 AND b = 1) OR c = 0 THEN xyz ELSE 0))
```

I could see lot of CASE with AND but with no OR.

And one more thing is this is need for a SELECT query like

```
Select x,y,z, SUM(( CASE WHEN .....))
```

from table.

Any help will be appreciated

```
CREATE PROCEDURE abc
@sid int
AS
BEGIN
SELECT
  Column1,
  Column2,
  Column3,
  SUM((CASE WHEN ((a = 1 AND b != 0 ) OR (c = 720)) THEN Amount ELSE 0 END)) 
     AS total
FROM view 
WHERE sid = @sid
END
```

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself?  It looks syntactically correct to me.  Also please tell us what RDBMS you are using.

Comment: i tried it but unfortunately the result is not what i expected. Iam using MSSQL

Comment: Please show us the full query, formatted in a readable way (with each line having 4 spaces in front), along with the exact error output you have.

Comment: Looks like you're just missing an `END`. Also, it's a `CASE` *expression*, not a *statement*. It computes a *value*.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen edited the question with my SP
SP is not throwing any error but the result what iam getting is not correct.

Comment: try removing the comma after total, put view(reserved word) in square brackets and it seems your real issue is that you need GROUP BY in the end of your query

Comment: a, b and c in `SUM((CASE WHEN ((a = 1 AND b != 0 ) OR (c = 720)) THEN Amount ELSE 0 END)) AS total` I suppose are something like `Int` and not `Char`. Wright?

Answer (score 0):

I've not been able to test this, but what you need is the following. There may be a *smarter* way of writing this.

```
SELECT
    Column1,
    Column2,
    Column3,
    SUM(NewAmount) AS TOTAL
FROM
SELECT
    Column1,
    Column2,
    Column3,
    CASE 
        WHEN (a = 1 AND b != 0 ) OR c = 720 THEN Amount 
        ELSE 0 
    END
    AS NewAmount
FROM 
    view 
GROUP BY
    Column1,
    Column2,
    Column3
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Select
    Column1,
    Column2,
    Column3,
    Sum(
        Case
            When ( ( a = 1 ) And ( b != 0 ) ) Or ( c = 720 ) Then Amount 
            Else 0 
        End
    ) As total
From 
    view 
Where
    sid = ...
Group By
    Column1, Column2, Column3
```

if a, b and c are numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want readable solution you could avoid using multiple statement and a lot of round brackets.

```
CASE WHEN A OR B OR C THEN amount
     ELSE 0
END
<=>
CASE WHEN A THEN amount              -- this condition will be evalued first
     WHEN B THEN amount              -- second
     WHEN C THEN amount              -- and third
     ELSE 0
END
```

In your case:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE abc
   @sid int
AS
BEGIN
SELECT
  Column1,
  Column2,
  Column3,
  [total] = SUM(CASE 
                   WHEN c = 720          THEN Amount
                   WHEN a = 1 AND b != 0 THEN Amount 
                   ELSE 0 
                END)  
FROM view 
WHERE sid = @sid
GROUP BY Column1, Column2, Column3
END
```

Note that you need to use `GROUP BY` for columns that aren't wrapped with aggregation functions.

---

Second thing I would use [user defined table valued function](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189294%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) instead of stored procedure:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[abc](@sid int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
    SELECT
      Column1,
      Column2,
      Column3,
      [total] = SUM(CASE 
                       WHEN c = 720          THEN Amount
                       WHEN a = 1 AND b != 0 THEN Amount 
                       ELSE 0 
                    END)  
    FROM view 
    WHERE sid = @sid
    GROUP BY Column1, Column2, Column3
);
```

Then I could do whatever I want with resultset:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[abc](1)
WHERE Column1 = 'xxx'
```